# Strange difference between .net 3.5 and .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a code

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x80, 1, 192, 33, 0 };

if (bytes[0] != 0x80 || ((bytes[1] & ~1) != 0) || bytes[4] != 0)
{
//signature wrong (.net 4.0 result)
}
else
{
//signture okay (.net 3.5 result)
}
```

In .net 3.5 expression evaluates as false, but in 4.0 it evaluates as true. My question is why? and how can i check all of my old (.net 3.5) code to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Can you split the condition to identify which is causing the difference?

Comment: the most strangest thing - then i'm eveluates this expression in Watch window (both for .net 3.5 and for 4.0) i've got:
    bytes[0] != 0x80 false bool
    ((bytes[1] & ~1) != 0) false bool
    bytes[4] != 0 false bool
    (bytes[0] != 0x80 || ((bytes[1] & ~1) != 0) || bytes[4] != 0) false bool

Comment: I just put this in a console app and targetted both 3.5 and 4.  Both end up in the `else`.

Comment: In my computer .`.Net 3.5` and older evaluates false. `.Net4` and later evaluates true.

Comment: watch window evaluates all subexpressions and the whole expression as false, but debugger moves to different branches in .net3.5 and 4.0. I'm using VS2015 if it matters.

Comment: ohh yeah. i'm not the only one.

Comment: @qmor It might matter - that means you've probably got .net 4.6 and are therefore using the new jitter.  Try targetting x86 rather than x64/any cpu - that will force the old jitter.  The new jitter has been far from bug free.  Haven't upgraded here so can't confirm.

Comment: In my computer the result is always `false`. I don't have VS2015 nor `.Net 4.6` installed, maybe thats the root of the problem ?

Comment: changing target to x86 solve the problem. But why? is it a bug or normal behaviour? how can i check my code to this possible incorrect evaluations?

Comment: this is cool. i put breakpoint at if part. all expressions evaluates to false but still it goes inside `if`. well `false|false|false = true` i didnt know this!

Comment: .NET 4.6 introduced a new JIT compiler (the bit that takes your compiled code and actually turns it into runnable machine code at runtime), but only for 64 bit apps.  32bit apps use the old one.  The new JIT compiler has had several (some pretty dramatic) bugs.  I suspect you've found another.  It all seems fine in the debugger because that triggers different behaviour.

Comment: no in debugger results are same for me. but ok its a bug. and yes 32 bit fixes the problem

Comment: See [this blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2015/07/27/why-you-should-wait-on-dotnet-46/) where the Stack Overflow team found one.  Towards the bottom it shows a registry key you can set to disable use of the new jitter - if you have production code that depends on this, I would recommend possibly going and disabling it _now_.

Comment: i'm using .net 4.0 not 4.5. Are this bug is present in all .net versions higher than 3.5?

Comment: There are only 2 (ish) underlying runtimes - 2 and 4.  .NET 3.5 runs on 2.  .NET 4 runs on, well, 4.  The 4.6 update means the new jitter will run on anything targetting >= 4, which is why 3.5 is fine.

Comment: thanks for answer, James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it's not lost in the comments, **I believe you have hit a bug in RyuJIT, the new JIT compiler for 64 bit applications in .NET 4.6**.

This is not the first one, for example see [this blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2015/07/27/why-you-should-wait-on-dotnet-46/) showing how the Stack Overflow team tracked down another issue.

As discussed in the comments, it is not triggered if you target .NET 3.5, nor if you target x86 in .NET 4.

*This* bug may or may not have been reported to Microsoft yet - if anyone is aware of a bug report for this, or has .NET 4.6 installed to track down the underlying cause more, feel free to edit.

Comment: Made this CW as it could be an important issue, so anyone feel free to update if they have more info.

Comment: Can't dig further to see how related this is at the moment, but Nick Craver (of Stack Overflow - see blog link above) has [confirmed](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/656872674245914624) that there are at least _some_ issues with bit wise stuff on ryujit.